# How to change the narration of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, narration

"Going to marry a banker's daughter ,are you,jimmy?" said Ben to himself.

Source - "The Retrieved Reformation"

Comment: change to what?

Comment: you mean from direct to indirect speech?

Comment: Yes I meant to indirect speech

Comment: @Lucyfer: The abysmal quality of the answers here probably reflects the poorly-presented question. As you can't be bothered to edit that comment into the question text itself, I think it's **Unclear what you're asking**.

Answer (score 1):

Ben asked himself if Jimmy wanted to marry the banker's daughter.
Ben wondered if Jimmy wanted to marry the banker's daughter.

You can't expect to capture all the nuances of direct speech if you switch to indirect speech. You'll have the essential content, but not the tone of voice or the manner of speaking. Question: why do you want to change it in the first place?

Comment: Well I have an exam this weekend and I came across this and thought how weird would it be in the indirect speech.

Comment: Well, if a character in a novel had that thought but didn't say it out loud, indirect speech would be the usual way of conveying it. You see it in novels all the time.

Answer (score -2):

Ben is astonished that how Jimmy was decided to marry the banker's daughter.

Comment: This is not grammatical. Please edit it into grammatical English.

Comment: It's also a misunderstanding of "jimmy".

Comment: @Matt Эллен♦: Not "grammatical" today, perhaps. But [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+was+decided+to&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20was%20decided%20to%3B%2Cc0) supports my belief that a century or two ago, *to be decided* was more capable of being used the same way we still accept *to be resolved, to be committed* today.

Comment: @F *Was decided* is not the issue here. The sentence should use **either** *that* or *how,* but not both. *That* on its own is probably preferable.